# Unzip local file and delete original in Dockerfile image build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, zip, compressed-files, tar.gz

I'm trying to uncompress a file and delete the original, compressed, archive in my `Dockerfile` image build instructions. I need to do this because the file in question is larger than the `2GB` limit set by Github on large file sizes (see [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3811)). The solution I'm pursuing is to compress the file (bringing it under the `2GB` limit), and then decompress when I build the application. I know it's bad practice to build large images and plan to integrate a external database into the project but don't have time now to do this.

I've tried various options, but have been unsuccessful.

1. Compress the file in `.zip` format and use `apt-get` to install `unzip` and then decompress the file with `unzip`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

#install unzip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install unzip

WORKDIR /app

COPY /data/databases/file.db.zip /data/databases

RUN unzip /data/databases/file.db.zip && rm -f /data/databases/file.db.zip

COPY ./ ./
```

This fails with `unzip:  cannot find or open /data/databases/file.db.zip, /data/databases/file.db.zip.zip or /data/databases/file.db.zip.ZIP.` I don't understand this, as I thought `COPY` added files to the image.

2. Following this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840831/how-to-download-and-unzip-in-dockerfile), I compressed the large file with `gzip` and tried to use the `Docker` native `ADD` command to uncompress it, i.e.:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app

ADD /data/databases/file.db.gz /data/databases/file.db

COPY ./ ./
```

While this compiles without error, it does not decompress the file, which I can see using `docker exec -t -i clean-dash /bin/bash` to explore the image directory structure. Since the large file is a `gzip` file, my understanding is `ADD` *should* decompress it, i.e. from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add).

How can I solve these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) only decompresses local tar files, not necessarily compressed single files.  It may work to package the contents in a tar file, even if it only contains a single file:

```sh
ADD ./data/databases/file.tar.gz /data/databases/
```

```sh
(cd data/databases && tar cvzf file.tar.gz file.db)
docker build .
```

If you're using the first approach, you must use a multi-stage build here.  The problem is that each `RUN` command generates a new image layer, so the resulting image is always the previous layer *plus* whatever changes the `RUN` command makes; `RUN rm a-large-file` will actually result in an image that's slightly larger than the image that contains the large file.

The [BusyBox](https://busybox.net) tool set includes, among other things, an implementation of **unzip**(1), so you should be able to split this up into a stage that just unpacks the large file and then a stage that copies the result in:

```sh
FROM busybox AS unpack
WORKDIR /unpack
COPY data/databases/file.db.zip /
RUN unzip /file.db.zip


FROM python:3.8-slim
COPY --from=unpack /unpack/ /data/databases/
```

In terms of the Docker image any of these approaches will create a single very large layer.  In the past I've run into operational problems with single layers larger than about 1 GiB, things like `docker push` hanging up halfway through.  With the multi-stage build approach, if you have multiple files you're trying to copy, you could have several `COPY` steps that break the batch of files into multiple layers.  (But if it's a single SQLite file, there's nothing you can really do.)

Comment: I've found a solution based on your suggestion. Your answer for (1), as written, didn't work; `file.db` was not in `app/data/databases/` after compiling. Could this involve the `COPY ./ ./` line? I altered your answer by copying `file.db` to `/`, e.g. `COPY --from=unpack /unpack/file.db /`, and then moving it after running `COPY ./ ./`, e.g. `RUN mv /file.db ./data/databases`. I hesitate to post this as the answer (or edit yours), because I feel that I'm missing something fundamental. But it works. Any insights?

Comment: In my example (and in the original question) the right-hand side of `COPY` is an absolute path `/data/databases`.  If you want it relative to the current `WORKDIR` you can change that to `./data/databases`.

Comment: I tried that and it also didn't work. When I did that, `COPY ./ ./` failed with `cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/otpsgzmz84h3w4nlv93qvptdo/merged/app/data/databases`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @David Maze's answer, the following worked, which I post here for completeness.

```
#unpacks zipped database
FROM busybox AS unpack
WORKDIR /unpack
COPY data/databases/file.db.zip /
RUN unzip /file.db.zip

FROM python:3.8-slim
COPY --from=unpack /unpack/file.db /

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

#move the unpacked db and delete the original
RUN mv /file.db ./data/databases && rm -f ./data/databases/file.db.zip
```