# Dockerfile detect ADD unpack failure

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Say I have a simple dockerfile:

```
ADD data.tar.gz .
```

If `data.tar.gz` is corrupted, then `ADD` will silently add the corrupted file instead of untarring it. Is there any way of detecting this failure? This happened to me because a Git LFS pointer failed to be resolved and so it built the docker image with the LFS pointer instead of unpacking the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COPY` + `RUN` instead:

```
COPY data.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xzf data.tar.gz && rm data.tar.gz
```

The `RUN` command will fail if `data.tar.gz` is not a compressed tar archive.

As mentioned in the comments, this will negatively affect the image size. If image size is a concern, you can avoid this penalty with multi-stage builds:

```
# Unpack stage
FROM busybox as unpack
COPY data.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xzf data.tar.gz && rm data.tar.gz

# Main image
FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=unpack /data ./data
```

Comment: Note that this will negatively affect the image size (COPY'ed file will keep occupying space in first layer even if you `rm` it)

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? (image size and failure detection)?

Comment: Looks like if you do the copy/run as a part of a multi-stage build you can avoid the image size increase: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71784746/2516916

Comment: Yeah, multi-stage build resolves this issue - it's more of a warning for those who'll just blindly copy this code snippet. Not sure they'll read comments, but I have tried at least...

Comment: I promoted your comment to a post edit so hopefully more people see it